# Multiple accordions

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to implement multiple accordions in a webpage but there seems to be a problem with my code that I just can't figure out.
Here is my code:

$k=0;

```
function accordion($i,$rez1)
{

    $acc_rez="<div class=\"tab-pane\" id=\""."$i"."\">rnd txt"."$i"."accordion"."$i";
    $acc_rez.="<div class=\"accordion"."$i"."\" id=\"accordion"."$i"."\">"; 
    $limit = count($rez1['data']);
    for($j=0; $j<$limit; $j++)
    {
        $acc_rez.="<div class=\"accordion-group\">";
        $acc_rez.="<div class=\"accordion-heading\">";
        $acc_rez.="<a class=\"accordion-toggle\" data-toggle=\"collapse\" data-parent=\"#accordion"."$i"."\" href=\"#collapse"."$k"."\">";

        $acc_rez.="<p>".$rez1['data'][$j]['id']. "</p>";

        $acc_rez.="</a></div>";

        $acc_rez.="<div id=\"collapse"."$k"."\" class=\"accordion-body collapse in\">";
        $acc_rez.="<div class=\"accordion-inner\"> random text number "."$j";
        $acc_rez.="</div></div></div>";
        $k++;
    }



    $acc_rez.="</div></div>\n";

    return $acc_rez;
}
```

This php function is called more times (i have a for loop, with i=0 to n),thus the ideea of creating many accordions for different tabs that i have.

The problem I have is that when i load the page and click on a tab, to see an accordion, all the accordion tabs are open and on all except the first tab i can't click any group item

Thanks for any help!

Comment: could you give us your javascript, I think maybe you're only coding it for a single class, where your php is printing out multiple class names, that's why it only works for the first one

Comment: can you make sure that in the rendered accordion code all the elements have a unique id ?

Comment: click the "answer your own question" link, paste your javascript in the question and explain in your answer what the problem was, this way other people who get the same problem can also benefit from it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to resolve the problem thanks to Maximus2012.

$k is a global variable which i use in giving different elements different names.
The problem was that I forgot to declare it as global in my function,and thus making it give identical values for different elements of my accordion.
Adding the global $k; at the beginning of my function made everything work.

Thanks to all that have made an input here!